# Why can't a "with" predicate be always used?

Tags: grammar

> Goblins are a male race but possess the ability to breed with any race
>   with the pregnancy always resulting in goblin children.
>
> Someone summoned goblins that possess the ability to breed with any
>   race **with the pregnancy always resulting in goblin children**.

Can someone explain to me why the second sentence sounds and is incorrect while the first is fine, and how we can reword the second sentence with the word "with" and without putting it in two separate sentences?

Comment: Both are fine. Why do you think there's a difference? (Aside from the words before *possesss* in each sentence.)

Comment: But in the second sentence it sounds off, because the with predicate is an aside, while the that predicate defines the word goblins. Not sure if there's any rule for this though. That's why I asked.